# How to split a text into a vector, where each entry corresponds to an index value assigned to each unique word?

Tags: r, dplyr, cpu-word, stringi

Let's say I have a document with some text, like this, from SO:

```
doc <- 'Questions with similar titles have frequently been downvoted and/or closed. Consider using a title that more accurately describes your question.'
```

I can then make a dataframe where every word has a row in a df:

```
library(stringi)
dfall <- data.frame(words = unlist(stri_extract_all_words(stri_trans_tolower(doc))))
```

We'll add a third column with its unique id. To get the ID, remove duplicates:

```
library(dplyr)
uniquedf <- distinct(data.frame(words = unlist(stri_extract_all_words(stri_trans_tolower(doc)))))
```

I'm struggling with how to match the rows against the two dataframes to extract the row index value from `uniquedf` as a new row value for `df`

```
alldf <- alldf %>% mutate(id = which(uniquedf$words == words))
```

A dply method like this doesn't work.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

To give an even simpler example to show the expected output, I'd like a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  words id
1     to  1
2     row  2
3     zip  3
4     zip  3
```

Where my starting word vector is: `doc <- c('to', 'row', 'zip', 'zip')` or `doc <- c('to row zip zip')`. The id column adds a unique id for each unique word.

Comment: Maybe add your expected output here if possible.  I'm not even sure your question is a dupe, but if you show what you are trying to do, someone can edit your title.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've added.

Comment: Simply `dfall$id <- match(dfall$words, unique(dfall$words))` and avoid the second step all together. Or `dfall$id <- as.numeric(factor(dfall$word))` if the index order doesn't matter.

Comment: @DavidArenburg That is perfect.. and much faster than sapply. I'll accept if you post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cheap way using `sapply`

**data**

```
doc <- 'Questions with with titles have frequently been downvoted and/or closed. Consider using a title that more accurately describes your question.'
```

**function**

```
alldf=cbind(dfall,sapply(1:nrow(dfall),function(x) which(uniquedf$words==dfall$words[x])))

colnames(alldf)=c("words","id")
> alldf
        words id
1   questions  1
2        with  2
3        with  2
4      titles  3
5        have  4
6  frequently  5
7        been  6
8   downvoted  7
9         and  8
10         or  9
11     closed 10
12   consider 11
13      using 12
14          a 13
15      title 14
16       that 15
17       more 16
18 accurately 17
19  describes 18
20       your 19
21   question 20
```

Comment: looks like with got duplicated there? did you do that for demonstration?

Comment: yes I did it in purpouse as your example did not have any duplication

Comment: I am a dope. Thank you.